# HTML image on webpage to download PDF File

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Is there a sample way for the user to download, save the PDF file I have on my webpage?

Currently I have:

```
<tr><td><a href="../Presentation.pdf"><img src="../../images/speakernotes.png"/></a>
```

which just opens the file and does not save it. Looking for a easy way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the browser and PDF reader installed. Some modern browsers have a built in PDF reader. So the only way to download from the link would be `Right Click` > `Save link as..`

Comment: Avoid ../ paths wherever possible

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked). — Yes, it is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML5 you can use the download attribute.  Here is an example by [Google](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html).

Another [example](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the content-disposition header which will force the `Save As..` dialog to the user.

So on your image, you can link to say a handler which will serve the PDF, or perhaps do a postback in an `ImageButton` and then serve the file.

```
 String FileName = "FileName.pdf";
 String FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/yourPath");
 System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
 response.ClearContent();
 response.Clear();
 response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");
 response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
 response.Flush();
 response.End();
```