# Download button code isn't working

Tags: html, download

For some reason this code isn't prompting a download. Instead it's plating the file once clicked. Any idea's?

```
<form class="download" method="get" action="http://reelcameras.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/reel-intro.m4v">
    <button class="button" title="Download" type="submit">
        <span><span><span><span>Download!</span></span></span></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: <form class="download" method="get" action="http://reelcameras.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/reel-intro.m4v"><button class="button" title="Download" type="submit"><span><span><span><span>Download!</span></span></span></span></button></form>

Comment: what's with all the `span`s :O

Comment: possible duplicate of [(HTML) Download a PDF file instead of opening them in browser when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked)

Comment: I just having styled the button in css yet. they are there for aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has a video player with a browser plugin, it will try and play the file in the browser.

What you can do however, is add a rule to your `.htaccess` file, and it will change the `MIME` type, so the browser thinks that it's an .exe, and prompt the user to save the file, rather than actually playing the video file in the browser.

Add this rule to your `.htaccess` file.

```
AddType application/octet-stream .m4v
```

Note, for every video filetype that you have on the site, you will have to add a rule.

Comment: I have just added that rule to the .htaccess but im still getting a play prompt in window.