# download HTML5 mp4 video using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

Hi I have video tag of HTML5, I want to give a "Download" button to user, where User can able to click and download that video.
I know user can download video by right click on browsers, but i want to give this feature on my button.

I am using simple code

```
$('submit').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'myvideo.mp4';
});
```

but it redirect me to video url not shows download popup that i want.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the download attribute but it is not supported in all browsers. If you want to ensure download everywhere, you have to set the right headers serverside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 browsers now allow you to add the `download` attribute to `<a>` tags to achieve this in your DOM. You cannot do this in pure javascript.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794432/5203655

If however, you have access to the server response, then in PHP you could do something like

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
readfile('myvideo.mp4');
```

Comment: Note: the `download` attribute only works for same origin URLs. This means it won't work for a download of a video file hosted elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```js
$('submit').click(function() {
  $('<a/>',{
     "href":"The/video/src/path",
    "download":"video.mp4",
    id:"videoDownloadLink"
  }).appendTo(document.body);
  $('#videoDownloadLink').get(0).click().remove();

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on Meghans answer:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($filename) .'"');
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
readfile($filename);`
```

Thanks, @Meghan. I copied and changed your code.