# Is it possible to force file downloads in browsers with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, download

I'm have developed a SPA (Single Page Application) with AngularJS and I'm trying to force a pdf file download with AngularJS.

By the moment I only can open de pdf file in a new tab with the next code.

HTML view:

```
<a ng-click="download()"></a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.download = function(){
    $window.open('/cv.pdf', '_blank');
};
```

Is there any way to force the pdf download in the browser?

You can see this example in the following URLs:

www.juanmanuellopezpazos.es/curriculum (HTML View)

www.juanmanuellopezpazos.es/Curriculum.pdf (pdf file whose download I want to force)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution with [@kierandotco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919097/kierandotco) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36059913/5877929). The best way is something like this:

`<a href="host/file.pdf" download target="_self"></a>`

The `download` HTML5 attribute and `target` attribute with `_self` value do the trick.

Comment: This is not working for text files, any idea on how to download text files?

Answer (score 4):

I am done this in MVC.NET WITH ANGULAR JS.
It works fine with firefox also(Tested in version:50.0)
Write down following code in your function:

```
//in mvc view
<a ng-href="#"   title="{{attachments.FileName}} " ng-click="download(attachment.FilePath,attachment.FileName)">{{attachments.FileName}} </a>
```

```
// in .js file
 $scope.download = function download(pathoffile, filename) {
        $http.get(pathoffile, {
            responseType: "arraybuffer"
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.filedata = response.data; 
            var headers = response.headers(); 
            headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment";
            var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "octet/stream" });
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
            link.download = filename;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This previous question should provide quite a lot of information on this.
[(HTML) Download a PDF file instead of opening them in browser when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked)

In you're case I'd recommend just direct linking to the PDF and using the download attribute (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have a little problem. If I use your recommended option, AngularJS manage the route as an app route, not as a resource. Is there any way to avoid this situation?

Comment: Hi again! I found one solution. If you add the "target" option with the value "_self", the pdf file is correctly downloaded. The final solution would be <a href="host/cv.pdf" download target="_self">Download</a>, where host could be "localhost" or any other.

Comment: @JuanManuelLopezPazos super glad you got it working :)