# PDF file opening in browser instead of download

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="test.pdf" download target="_blank">download PDF file</a>
```

I want to download this file instead of opening in browser. Whenever I click on it it shows me test.pdf, but now downloading.

And one more thing that how to download file through JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(HTML) Download a PDF file instead of opening them in browser when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked)

Comment: problem maybe with the path of your test.pdf

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="/file/path/here.pdf" download >Download PDF</a>`

This is possible in HTML5 by using the `download` attribute. Why do you need to use JavaScript?

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download).

Comment: See user2085143's comment above.