# have a editable pdf directly download from web page and not open in browser

Tags: wordpress, pdf, download

Hello I have an editable pdf that needs to be directly downloadable. Embedding is a bit tricky so I've decided to just have it downloaded directly to user's computers. It's on a Wordpress site and I have it downloading directly but I am still able to open it in a browser.

Can someone assist?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question.  As noted at [(HTML) Download a PDF file instead of opening them in browser when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked) HTML5 provides an attribute that forces the browser to download files when clicked; but it's considered to be a less than desirable practice.  How a user interacts with a PDF should be left up to the user.