# Download PDF file forcefully instead of opening new tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

**Here's what i've done so far. I managed to download the file but it's giving me "object%200%object" on the url when i try to open the file.**

```
     fetch({
        url,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob', // important
        contentDisposition: 'attachment',
        contentType: 'application/pdf',
        mode: 'no-cors'
    })
    .then(r => r.blob())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const s = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');

        link.setAttribute('download', `test.pdf`);
        link.click();
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked?

Comment: @RamyaRamanathan Thanks for the response mate! Though it's keeps opening a new tab here's my code:

   
    `let path= "http://example.pdf";`
    `let save = document.createElement('a');`
    `save.href = path;`
    `save.download = 'test';`
    `save.target = '_blank';`
    `document.body.appendChild(save);`
    `save.click();`
    `document.body.removeChild(save);`