# JSF download button to PDF file on external site (non-HTML 5)

Tags: pdf, jsf, download, external-links

How do you best create a download button to a PDF file on an external site, that is **not on the current web server**?

** EDIT **:
PLEASE NOTE: we're currently not using HTML 5. I am not sure if we can switch. Please assume non-HTML 5.

I have tried a few things, including:

```
<h:outputLink value="https://www.external-site.de/media/pdf/Proxy-Configuration.pdf"
              target="_blank">
```

This navigates to the PDF in a new tab/window and shows the PDF inside the browser. Without the blank the new window stuff is omitted and the same happens.

I tried more, none of which I believe should be replicated here (none of them worked).

In any case, I want to show a download popup on the client immediately. I'd like to use some button component, as the requirement is a button. However, using a link and making it look like a button would be OK, too.

**Q**:

What is the correct/best approach to this using JSF/PrimeFaces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(HTML) Download a PDF file instead of opening them in browser when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked)

Comment: Hmmm. We're currently not using HTML5. It's been a question ever since, but no one has ever addressed it. Editing...

Comment: In this case the accepted answer on the linked QA should be true for you: "You can't do this with HTML." - or one of the other pre-html5 answers.