# HTML: How to download a pdf file using a link

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contentful

I am trying to download a `.pdf` document from the external database [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/) using an `HTML` link on a user interface as shown below.

**The problem** I have is that everytime I click the link "PROJECT NOTES" I am redirected to an error page. Why my link does not download the `pdf` file?

[image: map]

Below the code I am using:

```
import Client from '../Contentful';


class Sidebar extends React.Component {
state = {
    ships: []
};

async componentDidMount() {
    let response = await Client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'cards'
    });
    const ships = response.items.map((item) => {
        const {
            name,
            slug,
            projectnotes
        } = item.fields;
        return {
            name,
            slug,
            projectnotes
        };
    });

    this.setState({
        ships
    });
}


getFilteredShips = () => {
    // operations .......
};

render() {
    return (
        <div className="map-sidebar">
            {this.props.activeShipTypes}
            <pre>
                {this.getFilteredShips().map((ship) => {
                    console.log(ship);

                    return (
                        <Card className="mb-2">
                            <CardImg />
                            <CardBody>
                                <CardTitle>
                                    <h3 className="thick">{ship.name}</h3>
                                </CardTitle>
                                <Row style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
                                    <div className="buttoncontainer">
                                        <div className="btn btn-cards">
                                            <a className="buttonLink" href={ship.projectnotes}>
                                                Project Notes
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="btn btn-cards">
                                            <a className="buttonLink" href={ship.distancesandcontours}>
                                                Dist and Contours
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Row>

                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
                    );
                })}
            </pre>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Sidebar;
```

I can confirm that I am reading correctly the name of the field:

[image: field]

Maybe am I incorrectly assigning the path?

**EDIT 2**

I tried the following too but no download happened:

```
<a className="buttonLink" download={ship.projectnotes} href={ship.projectnotes}>Project Notes</a>
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I was able to implement the link to the document but after I started using the external container `Contentful`, the `pdf` is not downloadable, contrarily to what I was hoping. Maybe there is an error in how I am assigning the path?

2) After researching more this problem I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked) post which was useful. It seems that in this post the problem could be the download?

I am a little bit confused. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the `download` attribute to the `a`, it's quite [well supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=download).

Comment: Thanks for reading the question. I updated the question with **EDIT 2** above with your suggestion but nothing happened. Am I doing it still incorrectly?

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/ycwg6uc.png) is what I am getting. Is that helpful?

Comment: `download` is a Boolean attribute, it doesn't need a value (here) but that shouldn'T cause that issue. Is `ship.projectnotes` definitely the correct value? Perhaps the data has issues?

Comment: Yes, I tried with and without  attribute. I think is the correct value. How can I `console.log()` to make sure it actually is? Maybe I am setting the path incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like the path is wrong to me. You should be able to see the value of `href` in the browser, you can check there if it's correct or not.

Comment: Thanks and how do I check that?

Comment: Like, How can I `console.log()` the `href`?

Comment: You shouldn't need to? When your page loads in the browser, use the developer tools to see the value stored in the `href`attribute of the `a` element? But you are logging `ship` already, so you should be able to see the value of `projectnotes` in there?

Comment: Ok [this](https://i.imgur.com/pLWZq1p.png) is the `console.log()`, do you see something I don't see?

Comment: Yes! `projectnotes` is an object, so you probably need to use `ship.projectnotes.fields.file.url` as the value for `href`.

Comment: Ok I see. Something just happened [here](https://i.imgur.com/zi7WJrT.png). I got an `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined`. The path is correct now, any idea?

Comment: Not without being able to see all of the code myself, it thinks that the object from which `fields` is being read, is undefined. I don't know why from here.

Comment: The code is in the question already. You can see `async componentDidMount()` with all the fields. Is that the function you were referring?

Comment: I mean being able to run it etc. It's easier to debug.

Comment: Found the error. Some of the fields in `Contentful` do not require a `pdf`. Therefore when there is no file, there is an unhandled error. So the path is correct, but there is no loop that handles empty fileds. You think you could help me with that if you have time? :)

Comment: I don't use React at all, but in your existing `render` function, isn't it possible to check for the missing fields in there and do something else other than returning the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

## Hello

Dear,
You an try to use this

```
<a className="buttonLink" href={yourDownloadFileLink} dowload>
     Click to download
</a>
```