# How to download an image from api in react without opening it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, imagedownload

I want to create a download button which will download image from api, I was able to do that but then got stuck in a problem . whenever I click on download button it does download the image but it also open the image in that page which makes it to leave the main page. I want it so that it won't open the image only download the image .

here is what I did

```
const download = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.href);
    fetch(e.target.href, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {},
    })
      .then((response) => {
        response.arrayBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer]));
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", "image.png"); //or any other extension
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };



<div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-4 text-center">
          {quote?.map((items) => (
            <div class="card" style={{ width: "18rem;" }}>
              <img src={items.img} class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }} class="card-title">
                  {items.name.replace(/_/g, " ")}
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text">{items.disc}</p>
                <Button
                  variant="outlined"
                  href={items.img}
                  onClick={ download }
                >
                  Download
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Do you control the API? Can you set [HTTP Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794317/4935162) when returning the image?

Comment: I have wrote the whole json file myself but I'm using image link from google images or other sites. I have tried other online api too.

Comment: Can you try - `window.open(file.url, '_self')`

Comment: it still opening the image in same tab

Comment: Comment all the code in `download` function & just do 
`window.open(e.target.href, '_self')`. `e.target.href` is a valid image url right?

Comment: It's just opening the image in the same tab. I want to download the image without opening it or navigating to other tab. @AseemGautam

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING Posted answer, seems I had a server configuration that forces download. Check my answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client side solution would only work if the requested image is **NOT** blocked by CORS policy.

```
  async function download(url) {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = await toDataURL(url);
    a.download = "myImage.png";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }

  function toDataURL(url) {
    return fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.blob();
      })
      .then((blob) => {
        return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      });
  }

  function onClick() {
    download("https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/profile/badge--acv-64.png");
  }
```

Complete working demo at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-water-o4ei73?file=/src/App.js:531-603)

If you have server access you can just add a `Content-disposition` header & then simply doing `window.open(url, '_self')` would download the image -

NGINX - `add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";`

Comment: it's saying its blocked by CORS policy. I think I think I have to learn more about CORS now. thanks for the answer