# Is there a way to Download PDF through a link using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webclient, rest-client

```
    Greeting to Everyone, I am new to Automation, Learning and Exploring
    My Problem Statement is:
```

I am trying to download PDF through a link, When I click on the link the PDF opens in a new window. By using Rest client I was able to download the pdf earlier (here end point was a single GET request), Now there is a backend changes happened where end point is changed to multiple post request.

The code I used so far:

```
        IWebDriver driver;
        var downloadloc = "C:\Users\Downloads" 
        public CookieContainer Cookies {get;set;}
        using(var client = new RestClient())
        {
          client.Endpoint = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath of the PDF link")).GetAttribute("href");
          client.DownloadFile(pdflink, downloadLoc);
        }
        public bool DownloadFile(string url,string flnm)
        {
          EndPoint = url;
         using (var webClient = new WebClient())
         {
           webClient.Headers("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
           (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
           webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, Cookies.GetCookieHeader(new Uri(EndPoint)));
           webClient.Proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
           webClient.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
           webClient.DownloadFile(EndPoint, flnm)
           
         }
        
        }

Does anyone have any possible solutions or insight into How to achieve the end goal? I'm still relatively new to programming and would appreciate any advice.
```

Please let me know, If any other information required..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any insights on this.

Comment: This might be related to this old question. (I am not sure if browsers changed in this field): [Force to open "Save As..." popup open at text link click for PDF in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html)

Comment: But you can also look at [(HTML) Download a PDF file instead of opening them in browser when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked)