# Force download file in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am calling API which gives me the below response

```
status  true
message "https://www.mywebsite.net/storage/pdf/15092023/1694768425.pdf"
```

and here is my react code for downloading the file

```
const downloadFile = async (file) => {
    const res = await customerServices.paymentInvoice( file );
    setTotalUrl(res.data);
    const fileName = /[^/]*$/.exec(file)[0];
    //const data = new Blob([res], { type:'application/pdf' });
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = res.data;
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    link.setAttribute("id", "custom-file-click");
    link.setAttribute("target", "blank");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  };
```

But it does not download the file. but open it in a new tab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(HTML) Download a PDF file instead of opening them in browser when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794255/html-download-a-pdf-file-instead-of-opening-them-in-browser-when-clicked)

Comment: As you can see I have already added that attribute `link.setAttribute("download", fileName);`.

Comment: @slientcoder   lookup to my answer

Answer (score 0):

as this guy suggested in another post even if you add download attribute
you need to add some permission in the backend so im assuming it might be a backend issue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794317/18018440