# How to forcefully download image in IE instead of open

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I want to download image in IE with  tag but instead of download it gets open in new tab. But IE did not support to HTML5  tag. Is there any solution so we can directly download image instead of open. I want to use only HTML and js because my application is customized web site in which SAS, html and JS is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["download" instead of "open" a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464804/download-instead-of-open-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Download attribute doesnt support in IE 
http://caniuse.com/#search=download%20attribute

you have to fixed this thing in server side
if you are on apache server, use below code in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fdl=1
RewriteRule .? - [T=application/octet-stream]
```

then it will work for you, hope it helps